# How to create polar chart in VS 2010

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, polar-coordinates

I came to know that "Polar Charts" (one type of chart) are used to plot the data which are in degrees. Now my task is to plot the radius and degrees entered by user in the textboxes.

I searched everywhere, but didn't get how to create this polar chart and add points to the chart. While searching I came through this [link] (http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedChart/Polar_Series.html) but they used their own stuff(classes and all). So I am posting here my query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This will get you started: (Chart Control for WinForms, included in .Net): http://www.dotnetperls.com/chart

Comment: @DrKoch Thanks for your suggestion. But It is like bar chart, i want Polar chart implementation.

Comment: This `Charts` package has all kinds of charts, just follow the tutorial, then read the docs.

Comment: To get you started: `Series S1 = chart1.Series[0];
            S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Polar;
            for (int d = 0; d <= 360; d+=15 )S1.Points.AddXY(d, 100 + d);`

Comment: @TaW Thanks. It is pretty good. I'll try to add points like you said.